# GRE - Percentage Question

Tags: fractions, gre-exam

> A full glass of juice is a mixture of 20% grape juice and 80% apple
>   juice. The contents of the glass are poured into a pitcher that is 200
>   percent larger than the glass. The remainder of the pitcher is filled
>   with 16 ounces of water. What was the original volume of grape juice
>   in the mixture?

I have approached the following problem as follow.

Let x represent the capacity of original color. Since we know the new glass is 200% larger than the original we can do 2x. We also know that in the new glass 16 ounces of water is added in addition to the original juice so we can setup the equation as follows.

2x = x + 16

Solving for x gives me 16.

Than i find 20% of 16 and get 3.6.

However the answer is wrong. Can anyone correct my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem's wording is tricky; $200\%$ larger means if the size is $x$, our new size is $2x$ more than the previous size, or $3x$.